# How to retrieve a part of a path name and assign it to a variable?

Tags: path, variable, tcsh, variable-substitution

I want to assign a part of my current working directory path name to a variable and use it in a script inside the directory itself.

For eg:

If my pwd is :

/home/desktop/project/ABC/abc/abc_123, is there a command to assign ABC to a variable, say $PROJECT_NAME?

I tried **dirname**, but it seems to be returning '**.**' for input 'pwd', and anyway I need one more step behind than what dirname can supposedly return.

Comment: have you tried using $PWD variable?

Comment: @Rakesh.N Yeah, in fact I did a second after I posted. But even that gives ' /home/desktop/project/ABC/abc/'  whereas I'm looking for 'ABC'

Comment: try this: var=$(echo $PWD|awk -F'/' '{print $5}')

Comment: Giving me "Illegal variable name" error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're tagging with `tcsh`:

```
set project = $cwd:h:h:t:q
```

Would set `$project` to the tail of the head of the head of the current directory (or basename of the dirname of the dirname). `:q` *quotes* the resulting text so no further expansions (like splitting or globbing) are done on it.

`pwd` is the command to print the current working directory. That command is not built-in `tcsh`. The current working directory is (unsurprisingly, or at least less surprisingly that with `ksh`'s `$PWD`) in the `$cwd` variable in `tcsh`.

Comment: Worked like a charm. What does the :q part add to it though?

Comment: @AmbareeshSJ see edit. The need to use that `:q` on all variable expansions, and the fact that there's no equivalent for command substitution are one of the many reasons using (t)csh is not recommended.

Comment: Oh alright. But I tried it without the :q and it seemed  to work just fine, hence the doubt. TY!

Comment: @AmbareeshSJ, try after `mkdir -p '*/a/b'; cd '*/a/b'` for instance.